# Does the iPhone Mail app mark gmail messages as spam?

Tags: ios, gmail, iphone, email

If I move a message to the Spam folder using the native mail app on the iPhone, will it be marked as spam on the gmail server? Or will the message just be moved to that folder? I'm connected to gmail via Exchange.

Comment: What about whitelisting? If I move the message from the Junk folder in iOS mail to my inbox, does it do the reverse and whitelist it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the message to the Spam folder will mark it as spam on the gmail server as well as moving it to the spam folder.